# Why does an argument $args after = sign not get expanded? ($args as parameter to jvm typical -D switch)

Tags: powershell, escaping, powershell-2.0

I have the following definition in my *profile.ps1 file:

```
if(Test-Path $env:M2_HOME){
    function mvn{
            $cmd = "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat"
            & $cmd $args
    }
}
```

When I define a function using this function in powershell like:

```
function d { mvn help:describe $args }
```

using like:

```
d -Dplugin=jar
```

everything is fine as opposed to defining the latter as:

```
function d { mvn help:describe -Dplugin=$args }
```

using like:

```
d jar
```

Is there some builtin to handle this corner case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to make sure you're passing the arguments as strings and ensure they're evaluated first:

```
function mvn{
  $cmd = "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat"
  & $cmd $args
}

function d { mvn "help:describe" "-Dplugin=$($args)" }
```

Answer (score 1):

for get argument through call function you should use like this

```
function test {
write-host $args[0]
write-host $args[1]
}

test stackoverflow powershell
```

output

```
stackoverflow
powershell
```

`stackoverflow` is `first argument` passed to function and `powershell` is `second argument` passed to function 
for every argument passed to function

```
function test {
foreach ($a in $args){
write-host "output:$args"
}
}
```

test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

output:

```
test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

for your function

```
 if(Test-Path $env:M2_HOME){
        function mvn{
                $cmd = "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat"
foreach ($arg in $args) {

                & $cmd $args}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need all arguments passed to the function.

Comment: daniel post edited test loop `foreach` for passed all arguments to function

Comment: Soheil thank you for the `Write-Host` tip, it really proved useful for me to verify that `$args` aren't expanded... and now for the surprise, as i found out eventually someone had a similar issue, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Someone seems to have made [a similar observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374892/3320256):
The reason seems `-D` being a special character in powershell more or less marking where exactly each particluar special option string determined by `-D` ends, at least this modification to my calling function then works for me:

```
function x {mvn help:describe `-Dplugin=$args}
```

Sure it would be nice to handle such occasions in the hosting function somehow (`mvn` definition in my *profile.ps1), but that solutions rather seems out of scope of my question.