# Maven -D options not working in Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, windows-7, java-8, maven-3

Maven commands which has -D options does not work for me. I tried running command

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip
```

and get error message as

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "?Dmaven.test.skip". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]`

When I copied the same command in a batch file & tried calling the batch, it ran successfully. Below are the environment details
Operating System : Windows 7
JDK : 1.8.0_40
Maven : 3.3.1

I tried running in MS Dos & Powershell, but getting same error in both the places. 
I felt it is because of some character encoding, not sure. Please suggest.

Comment: Your "dash" is probably not a real dash/minus, but rather a "em dash". Be sure to type the command with your keyboard, not copy-pasting from a Word/Outlook document

Comment: I tried typing in the command too, but made no difference.

Comment: the fact that the error message shows a `?` instead of the dash shows that your dash is not a proper dash. It may be due to your keyboard configuration. If you just copy paste this it should work fine: `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip`.

Comment: I copied the command, but that did not help too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Maven using \`mvn -D\` argument within Microsoft Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347985/cannot-run-maven-using-mvn-d-argument-within-microsoft-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally figure out based on all the trials which were suggested by Tome , Assylias, Manish Thank a lot.
The output of command was not consistent as "dash" was giving problem as it sometimes becomes a weird character when copied from a file. Also when I was typing the command, sometimes it works & at times it was failing (probably because of some command was executed from history). 
So then I deleted all previous commands & started typing every other time & it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the options in double quotes (`"`):

`mvn clean install -D"maven.test.skip"`

Comment: Thanks, but got some response.