# how to depoly Vaadin chart app to heroku

Tags: github, heroku, charts, vaadin

I am trying to deploy my Vaadin chart app to Heroku. I can locally build it by IDE and all works fine.

I have free developer license saved into my home directory. When I tried to deploy it to Heroku by Heroku cli. It tried to build a maven project. Then it fails with the error as:-

> [ERROR] License for Vaadin Charts 4 not found. Go to vaadin.com/pro
>   for more details.

I follow doc as:-
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/addons/addons-cval.html.

mvn -Dvaadin..developer.license=L1cen5e-c0de package. If I tir it, it gives error as:-
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".vaadin.charts.developer.license=xxMY_KEYxxxx"

I tried also this:-
https://github.com/vaadin/maven-plugin/issues/49

So how to deploy or add license info for Vaadin chart app while deploying to Heroku?

**Update**

[image]

Adding this picture to show Tazavoo about my command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message and what you said you wrote doesn't make sense to me. The `charts` part is missing from your first command, should be:

`mvn -Dvaadin.charts.developer.license=L1cen5e-c0de package`

No extra spaces. No double dots.

Comment: not to make any more mistake I copied your text and replace the license key with my license key. Still same error: Unknown lifecycle phase ".charts.developer.license=dda31963-d1b3-43bf-be1a-6XXXX

Comment: Do you get the same if you just copy-paste the whole message and run it? Of course then the license key will be wrong but it shouldn't complain about anything... I tried running that and no problems, also with my real license key, although in a project that doesn't depend on charts. I can reproduce your issue if I put a space between `vaadin` and `.charts`

Comment: Ah, might be a Powershell/Windows thing! Judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347985/cannot-run-maven-using-mvn-d-argument-within-microsoft-powershell-but-works) surrounding it in single quotes might help!

`mvn '-Dvaadin.charts.developer.license=L1cen5e-c0de' package`

Comment: mvn '-Dvaadin.charts.developer.license=L1cen5e-c0de' package worked perfectly. It works both Powershell and normal console.